# node.js + socket.io broadcast from server, rather than from a specific client?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm building a simple system like a realtime news feed, using node.js + socket.io.

Since this is a "read-only" system, clients connect and receive data, but clients never actually send any data of their own.  The server generates the messages that needs to be sent to all clients, no client generates any messages; yet I do need to broadcast.

The [documentation for socket.io's broadcast](http://socket.io/#how-to-use) (end of page) says

> To broadcast, simply add a `broadcast` flag to `emit` and `send` method calls. Broadcasting means sending a message to everyone else except for the socket that starts it.

So I currently capture the most recent client to connect, into a variable, then `emit()` to that socket *and* `broadcast.emit()` to that socket, such that this new client gets the new data *and* all the other clients.  But it feels like the client's role here is nothing more than a workaround for what I thought socket.io already supported.

Is there a way to send data to all clients based on an *event initiated by the server*?

My current approach is roughly:

```
var socket;

io.sockets.on("connection", function (s) {
  socket = s;
});

/* bunch of real logic, yadda yadda ... */

myServerSideNewsFeed.onNewEntry(function (msg) {
  socket.emit("msg", { "msg" : msg });
  socket.broadcast.emit("msg", { "msg" : msg });
});
```

Basically the events that cause data to require sending to the client are all server-side, not client-side.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Why not just do like below?

```
io.sockets.emit('hello',{msg:'abc'});
```

Comment: When I tried that I got an error that `io.sockets.emit` is not a defined function.

Comment: Hmm, seems I actually tried `io.sockets.broadcast.emit()`, my bad, this does seem to work!

Comment: I'll change the selected answer as this is a lot simpler, thanks.

Comment: If you have something simple indeed that will work, if you need to iterate through the sockets and only sent a message if a certain condition is met then my solution is more general.

Comment: @alessioalex, thanks, I appreciate your solution; I learnt something new. However, in this case I'm specifically trying to avoid the need to iterate. This is a really simple system but needs to scale as best as possible, as it's visible site-wide and is updated every 7 seconds.

Comment: Absolutely, `io.sockets.broadcast.emit` is the best fit here.

Comment: As of v1.0.4, I am able to simply write ``io.emit('hello',{msg:'abc'})`` and it works just as well.

Answer (score 5):

Since you are emitting events only server side, you should create a custom [EventEmitter](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.6/api/events.html) for your server.

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);
    events = require('events'),
    serverEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  // here you handle what happens on the 'newFeed' event
  // which will be triggered by the server later on
  serverEmitter.on('newFeed', function (data) {
    // this message will be sent to all connected users
    socket.emit(data);
  });
});

// sometime in the future the server will emit one or more newFeed events
serverEmitter.emit('newFeed', data);
```

Note: `newFeed` is just an event example, you can have as many events as you like.

**Important**

The solution above is better also because in the future you might need to emit certain messages only to some clients, not all (thus need conditions). For something simpler (just emit a message to all clients no matter what), `io.sockets.broadcast.emit()` is a **better fit** indeed.

Comment: Ah, I was doing something very similar before, albeit with more of a conventional observer design pattern (it's my first day using node), but I was concerned that the loop was inefficient. New messages are broadcast every 7 seconds to around 10,000 clients.

Comment: I assumed broadcast used an efficient algorithm, but maybe it's just an abstraction.  I'll try your approach ;)

Comment: A bit off-topic, but do I need to handle disconnect, or will socket.io/node take care of it for me?  Seems like I would end up with dead event observers.

Comment: You don't need to handle disconnect.