# node.js app send broadcast message socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm newbie to both node.js and socket.io but i want to write a small application to broadcast some values to connected clients.
I don't know two thing first how can i fire socket.broadcast.emit or other broadcast functions in my other functions? in my app i have a function that calculate a value every second,and i want to send this value to all clients.
my second question is how i get this message in clients and use it in my other javascript functions?
i saw this before 
[node.js + socket.io broadcast from server, rather than from a specific client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588895/node-js-socket-io-broadcast-from-server-rather-than-from-a-specific-client) but failed to do what i want
thanks in advance
here is my code:

```
var cronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var snmp = require('snmp-native');
//var oid = [1, 3, 6, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0];
//var oid1 = [1,3,6,1,2,1,11,1];
//var oid2 = [1,3,6,1,4,1,2636,3,9,1,53,0,18];
//var oid3 = [1,3,6,1,2,1,2,2,1,11,18];
var intraffic = [1,3,6,1,2,1,2,2,1,10,18]; //inbound traffic
var outtraffic = [1,3,6,1,2,1,2,2,1,16,18]; //outbound traffic
var inpps = [1,3,6,1,4,1,2636,3,3,1,1,3,518]; //interface inbound pps
var outpps = [1,3,6,1,4,1,2636,3,3,1,1,6,518]; //interface out pps

var session = new snmp.Session({ host: '10.0.0.73', port: 161, community: 'Pluto@com' });
new cronJob('* * * * * *', function(){
    session.get({ oid:intraffic }, function (error, varbind) {
        var vb;
        if (error) {
            console.log('Fail :(');
        } else {
            vb=varbind[0];
            console.log(vb.oid + ' = ' + vb.value + ' (' + vb.type + ')');
        }

    });
}, null, true, "America/Los_Angeles");
```

Comment: Seems like the other question you have given has the solution for you. Are you getting any errors ? Can you post your code so far?

Comment: i don't changed the code so far because i don't know how to do that. i don't know how to send my value into the broadcast from other function

Comment: Can you post your  `Other` function.

Comment: Jayantha i post my function in my question post,it's snmp function which get some value from devices every second(using crone) i need this values(vb.value) to be broadcast to all connected clients

Answer (score 2):

For the first question is easy,

In your module, create a variable named io with the socket.io server instance and export it at the end. If all the functions are on the same module, you only need a global variable (that will be global only for that module)

-- mymodule.js --

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80); // Create socket.io server as usual
...
module.exports.io = io; // Add this at the end of mymodule.js


// Broadcast in the same module where the server is defined
io.sockets.emit('this', { will: 'be received by everyone' });
```

-- other_module.js --

```
var wsserver = require( 'mymodule.js' ); // Require your module as usual and assign it to a variable
...
// Usage of socket server to broadcast a message in another module
wsserver.io.sockets.emit('this', { will: 'be received by everyone' });
```